# Woocommerce Manually Increase $post_id to skip a series of order numbers

Tags: woocommerce, numbers, orders, skip

I am having an issue since reverting my site to a history state in which the $order_id was also reverted; however my 3rd party stock management has used a bunch of order Id's, about 100 out that will create a problem when I get to them and orders are re-made using old ID's that are already in the system.

I need to increase the count of the $order_id as to avoid this; seems easy enough but I have found NO support relating to this aside from digging around in the database and that seems unessisairy for something this simple.

I can manipulate the order number using the commonly found "add prefix or suffix to order number" but that affects all orders, past and future. So if I add a 0 to the end; all the old orders in the system suddenly also have a 0 added and it breaks the links to the external api managing the orders.

I need a way to just increase the $order_id by 100 ONLY on newly generated orders. I guess I could go post 100 articles or something tedious like that but I feel there should be a rather simple way to just increase the count on the site. Skip a few numbers then good to go y'know?

here is the code I used that changes all the orders; it is not helpful really but I mentioned it so here it is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'test_woocommerce_order_number', 1, 2 );
function test_woocommerce_order_number( $oldnumber, $order ) {
    $prefix = "AU-";
    $suffix = 0;

    return $prefix . $order->id . $suffix; 
}
```

This will change my order number from 10338 to: AU-103380  BUT it changes all orders in the system. I simply want to increase the counter so that new orders begin at 10438.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I simply made a hidden post and saved it 100 times. If you run into this issue and you need to skip 1,000 or 10,000+ values of the $order->id then my solution will not work for you. This worked for me; however "workaround-y" it may be.